# Display text over entire d3 force directed layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm working on a simple d3 force directed layout just to have some nodes displaying in the background and I'm trying to have text displayed on top of the entire layout. Does anyone know how I can make this happen? All I know how to do is append text to individual nodes, but I want it to display over all of the nodes.

Comment: Are you having further issues moving on? If your problem is solved then you should mark the answer that helped resolving the problem as **accepted**. This helps other people to find what they are looking for. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a `<g>` group element containing all of your `nodes`. You can getting the [bounding box](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/coords.html#BoundingBox) of the `<g>` svg element and then add and position a `<text>` element based on the bounding box coordinates.